# problems with drag-events showing something under the mouse

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm developing a visual scheduler control in WinForms. Simplified it's a `panel` with some bars on it. If a user presses `MouseDown` on a bar he should be able to move it vertically. Therefor i'm using the built-in drag and drop functionality of the `WinForms` controls. So far so good.

Now I wanna show the user a copy of the currently moving bar under the mouse cursor (50 % opacity) while he is moving the mouse vertically, so he gets a visual feedback, where the bar will get if he releases the mouse.

At the moment I'm using a `Form` with a picture of the bar in it showing it right above the mouse cursor. If I show the `Form` right under (behind) the cursor, I have troubles with the drag-events, because the drag events of the underlaying panel are firing rotational (`DragEnter`, `DragLeave`, `DragEnter`, `DragLeave`, and so on).

I think the problem is, that I have a control (the `Form` with the picture) under the mouse, which is not the panel.

Should I rather draw the image of the currently moving bar by handling the `Paint event`?

Hope you guys know what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this could be done purely in `GDI+` drawing the panels, draw while moving would be easy to add for this including opacity.

Comment: Giving feedback during drag+drop requires a GiveFeedback event handler on the drag source which sets e.UseDefaultCursor to false so you can assign the Cursor.Current property.  Nothing resembling what you are doing by the sound of it.  Maybe you don't actually like D+D and just want to move a control.

Comment: @Hans Passant It's a little bit more complicated. I need the D&D because the user can drag the bars also into a few other forms.

Comment: @OneFineDay: Actually my control isn't a real control. It's a panel in a Form. On which Paint-event should I do the drawing? Paint-event of the panel? I''m not very familiar with that.

Comment: Pure `GDI+` would use no controls, you would handle all the drawing in the control's paint event you host the drawings on. BTW a panel **is a** control.

Comment: I know, i just meant the whole thing i'm building is no custom control.. Ok, I'm gonna try that.